# Update/create postgres cube

Tags: postgresql, cube

Is it possible to update a single dimension for a cube?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE mycubes a SET
    data=
    set_ur_dim_cube_bounds(4, cube_ur_coord(b.data, 4))
FROM
    myothercubes b
WHERE
    a.id = b.id;
```

EDIT w/ more info:

I installed the cube extension using `create extension if not exists cube`
  and the table was created with something along the lines of:

```
CRAETE TABLE mycubes (id serial primary key, data cube);
```

Comment: you want to update one row of child table using parent table ? Please explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that simplest way for you will be get old value, change single dimension and update full cube value.

```
data=
    cube(
        array[cube_ll_coord(a.data, 1), cube_ll_coord(a.data, 2),
              cube_ll_coord(a.data, 3), cube_ll_coord(a.data, 4)],
        array[cube_ur_coord(a.data, 1), cube_ur_coord(a.data, 1),
              cube_ur_coord(a.data, 3), cube_ur_coord(b.data, 4)]
    )
```

Comment: I am going to go this route for now.  I added the part of the SQL statement I am using in the answer.

Comment: I hope that PostgreSQL developers will create function for update of single element in future.